# Duda con consulta mysql, problemas de seleccion

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un pequeño problema con una consulta, ya que quiero realizarla por medio de dos tablas, lo que pretendo es lo siguiente.

Tengo una tabla `users` con `roles`.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | refer      | username   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | alfa       | adminad    |
|  2 | adminad    | angelicaad |
|  3 | angelicaad | miguelad   |
|  4 | angelicaad | faisuri    |
|  5 | adminad    | gestionad  |
+----+------------+------------+
```

y una tabla usuarios sin ningún tipo de `rol`

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| usuario_ad | nombre      | apellido    |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| angelicaad | chilindrina | kiko        |
| angelicaad | chavo       | elocho      |
| adminad    | ramon       | valdez      |
| miguelad   | suchi       | sarmiento   |
| miguelad   | ana         | gil         |
| faisuri    | carlos      | saldarriaga |
| faisuri    | pepe        | cortizona   |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Mi intensión es que si en la tabla `users`, `angelicaad` agrego a `miguelad` y a `faisuri`, en la tabla usuarios, debe aparecer todos los usuarios de `miguelad`, `faisuri` y `angelicaad`, pero con esta consulta solo logro que aparezcan los de `miguelad` y `faisuri`, pero no `angelicaad`.

```
select usuario_ad, nombre 
from usuarios, users 
where users.refer="angelicaad" and usuarios.usuario_ad=username;
```

Que me hace falta?

Comment: Cual es el resultado que queres? lo podes agregar?

Comment: Claro, el resultado que quiero,, es que en la tabla usuarios, aparezcan todos. menos adminad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que esto:

```
select usuario_ad, 
       nombre 
       from usuarios
       where usuario_ad in (select username
                                   from users 
                                   where users.refer="angelicaad"
                            union
                            select "angelicaad"
                            );
```

Podría servirte:

- En una subconsulta obtenemos, los usuarios referidos por `angelicaad` y agregamos mediante un `union` a la propia `angelicaad`
- Luego simplemente obtenemos las filas de `usuarios` dónde `usuario_ad`se encuentre en la lista anterior

Comment: Pero Patricio en la zona de comentarios dice: **el resultado que quiero,, es que en la tabla usuarios, aparezcan todos. menos adminad**, esta consulta de la tabla usuarios solo devuelve a: *angelicaad* pero no a los demás o si?

Comment: @Aprendiz, esta consulta, a menos que me haya equivocado, debería retornar todos menos `adminad`.

Comment: pero que pu... excelente, muchas gracias maestro.